# TabularX - Cell content exiting

Tags: tabularx

I am trying to fix my vertical table, the age values are exiting the cell.

```
\begin{landscape}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|>{\hsize=1.5\hsize}X|*{12}{>{\hsize=0.75\hsize}X|}}
\hline
    & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Shu et al.}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{VRC}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{SRC}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{MSRC}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{NFRC}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{FSC}} \\ \hline
    & \makecell{Stable} & \makecell{Progr} & \makecell{Stable} & \makecell{Progr} & \makecell{Stable} & \makecell{Progr} & \makecell{Stable} & \makecell{Progr} & \makecell{Stable} & \makecell{Progr} & \makecell{Stable} & \makecell{Progr} \\ \hline
    \textbf{Subjects, No.} & 72 & 72 & 12 & 12 & 72 & 72 & 72 & 72 & 72 & 72 & 51 & 51 \\ \hline
    \textbf{F/M No.} & 29/43 & 22/50 & 3/9 & 3/9 & 29/43 & 29/43 & 29/43 & 29/43 & 35/37 & 35/37 & 19/32 & 20/31 \\ \hline
    \textbf{Age, mean +/- SD} & 61.3$\pm$10.09 & 61.45$\pm$11.44 & 66.5$\pm$10.5 & 68.1$\pm$6.9 & 61.0$\pm$8.8 & 61.2$\pm$8.6 & 60.7$\pm$6.4 & 60.7$\pm$9.3 & 62.0$\pm$9.4 & 62.0$\pm$9.2 & 60.3$\pm$8.6 & 63.8$\pm$8.9 \\ \hline
    \textbf{Hoehn \& Yahr Stage 1 (n)} & 47 & 25 & 0 & 0 & 32 & 32 & 32 & 32 & 32 & 32 & 22 & 22 \\ \hline
    \textbf{Hoehn \& Yahr Stage 2 (n)} & 47 & 25 & 12 & 12 & 40 & 40 & 40 & 40 & 40 & 40 & 29 & 29 \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\captionof{table}{Summary of cohorts constructed.}
\label{table:cohorts}
\end{landscape}
```

Here is how it looks:

[image]

Any recommended fix?

Answer (score 1):

An attempt using `tabularray` package.

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
    \begin{tblr}{
        colspec={X[l,1]*{12}{X[-0.6]}},
        column{1}={cmd=\bfseries},
        rowspec={*{7}{m{3em}}},
        row{1}={cmd=\bfseries},
        row{5}={cmd=\num[separate-uncertainty]},
        cell{5}{1}={guard},
        hlines,
    }
        & \SetCell[c=2]{c} Shu et al. & & \SetCell[c=2]{c} VRC & & \SetCell[c=2]{c} SRC & & \SetCell[c=2]{c} MSRC & & \SetCell[c=2]{c} NFRC & & \SetCell[c=2]{c} FSC & \\
        & Stable & Progr & Stable & Progr & Stable & Progr & Stable & Progr & Stable & Progr & Stable & Progr \\
        Subjects, No. & 72 & 72 & 12 & 12 & 72 & 72 & 72 & 72 & 72 & 72 & 51 & 51 \\
        F/M No. & 29/43 & 22/50 & 3/9 & 3/9 & 29/43 & 29/43 & 29/43 & 29/43 & 35/37 & 35/37 & 19/32 & 20/31 \\
        \textbf{Age, mean +/- SD} & 61.3 \pm 10.09 & 61.45 \pm 11.44 & 66.5 \pm 10.5 & 68.1 \pm 6.9 & 61.0 \pm 8.8 & 61.2 \pm 8.6 & 60.7 \pm 6.4 & 60.7 \pm 9.3 & 62.0 \pm 9.4 & 62.0 \pm 9.2 & 60.3 \pm 8.6 & 63.8 \pm 8.9 \\
        Hoehn \& Yahr Stage 1 (n) & 47 & 25 & 0 & 0 & 32 & 32 & 32 & 32 & 32 & 32 & 22 & 22 \\
        Hoehn \& Yahr Stage 2 (n) & 47 & 25 & 12 & 12 & 40 & 40 & 40 & 40 & 40 & 40 & 29 & 29 \\
    \end{tblr}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Explanation

1. `X[l,1]` flushes the text left, and `X[-0.6]` sets the width of the columns to at most 0.6 times the first column's width.
2. `column{1}={cmd=\bfseries}` and `row{1}={cmd=\bfseries}` formats the first row and column to bold.
3. `rowspec={*{7}{m{3em}}}` centers all the rows vertically, and sets the height of the rows to `3em`.
4. `row{5}={cmd=\num[separate-uncertainty]}` formats the entries in 5th row using the command `\num` from the `siunitx` package. This helps print the uncertainties better.
5. `cell{5}{1}={guard}` prevents the previous setting (row 5 formatting) from getting applied to the first column in 5th row, because it is not a number. `siunitx` would throw an error. This also clears the bold formatting applied to column 1 and hence it must be applied explicitly again here.
6. `hlines` draws lines before and after every row.
7. `SetCell[c=2]{c}` creates a multicolumn cell spanning two columns (hence `c=2`) and centers the text (the `{c}` part).

### Edit

To get `vlines` for the first row:

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{landscape}
        \begin{tblr}{
                colspec={|X[l,1] | *{12}{X[-0.6]}|},
                column{1}={cmd=\bfseries},
                rowspec={*{7}{m{3em}}},
                row{1}={cmd=\bfseries},
                row{5}={cmd=\num[separate-uncertainty]},
                cell{5}{1}={guard},
                hlines,
                vlines={1}{solid},
            }
            & \SetCell[c=2]{c} Shu et al. & & \SetCell[c=2]{c} VRC & & \SetCell[c=2]{c} SRC & & \SetCell[c=2]{c} MSRC & & \SetCell[c=2]{c} NFRC & & \SetCell[c=2]{c} FSC & \\
            & Stable & Progr & Stable & Progr & Stable & Progr & Stable & Progr & Stable & Progr & Stable & Progr \\
            Subjects, No. & 72 & 72 & 12 & 12 & 72 & 72 & 72 & 72 & 72 & 72 & 51 & 51 \\
            F/M No. & 29/43 & 22/50 & 3/9 & 3/9 & 29/43 & 29/43 & 29/43 & 29/43 & 35/37 & 35/37 & 19/32 & 20/31 \\
            \textbf{Age, mean +/- SD} & 61.3 \pm 10.09 & 61.45 \pm 11.44 & 66.5 \pm 10.5 & 68.1 \pm 6.9 & 61.0 \pm 8.8 & 61.2 \pm 8.6 & 60.7 \pm 6.4 & 60.7 \pm 9.3 & 62.0 \pm 9.4 & 62.0 \pm 9.2 & 60.3 \pm 8.6 & 63.8 \pm 8.9 \\
            Hoehn \& Yahr Stage 1 (n) & 47 & 25 & 0 & 0 & 32 & 32 & 32 & 32 & 32 & 32 & 22 & 22 \\
            Hoehn \& Yahr Stage 2 (n) & 47 & 25 & 12 & 12 & 40 & 40 & 40 & 40 & 40 & 40 & 29 & 29 \\
        \end{tblr}
    \end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Edit 3

Vertical lines surrounding each merged cell of the first row.

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{landscape}
        \begin{tblr}{
                colspec={|X[l,1] *{6}{| X[-0.6] X[-0.6]}|},
                column{1}={cmd=\bfseries},
                rowspec={*{7}{m{3em}}},
                row{1}={cmd=\bfseries},
                row{5}={cmd=\num[separate-uncertainty]},
                cell{5}{1}={guard},
                hlines,
            }
            & \SetCell[c=2]{c} Shu et al. & & \SetCell[c=2]{c} VRC & & \SetCell[c=2]{c} SRC & & \SetCell[c=2]{c} MSRC & & \SetCell[c=2]{c} NFRC & & \SetCell[c=2]{c} FSC & \\
            & Stable & Progr & Stable & Progr & Stable & Progr & Stable & Progr & Stable & Progr & Stable & Progr \\
            Subjects, No. & 72 & 72 & 12 & 12 & 72 & 72 & 72 & 72 & 72 & 72 & 51 & 51 \\
            F/M No. & 29/43 & 22/50 & 3/9 & 3/9 & 29/43 & 29/43 & 29/43 & 29/43 & 35/37 & 35/37 & 19/32 & 20/31 \\
            \textbf{Age, mean +/- SD} & 61.3 \pm 10.09 & 61.45 \pm 11.44 & 66.5 \pm 10.5 & 68.1 \pm 6.9 & 61.0 \pm 8.8 & 61.2 \pm 8.6 & 60.7 \pm 6.4 & 60.7 \pm 9.3 & 62.0 \pm 9.4 & 62.0 \pm 9.2 & 60.3 \pm 8.6 & 63.8 \pm 8.9 \\
            Hoehn \& Yahr Stage 1 (n) & 47 & 25 & 0 & 0 & 32 & 32 & 32 & 32 & 32 & 32 & 22 & 22 \\
            Hoehn \& Yahr Stage 2 (n) & 47 & 25 & 12 & 12 & 40 & 40 & 40 & 40 & 40 & 40 & 29 & 29 \\
        \end{tblr}
    \end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi there, thank you, I tired and it worked perfectly. How could I add a vertical line between the first row only ? 

|  Shu et al.    |    VRC        | ... | 
 Stable Progr Stable Progr

Comment: @turkishcoffee see my edit

Comment: thanks for the update, what I meant is a vertical line that goes from top all the way to bottom. in this case, the vertical line stops at the cell. I tried using `vlines={1,2,3,4,5,6,7}{solid}` but that puts lines around every cell.

Comment: also, can you help me with a similar table please? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/676411/tabularray-table-setcell-not-working-properly

Comment: @syriancoffee see my second edit.