# tabularray Table - SetCell not working properly

Tags: tabularray

I have the following table:

```
\begin{tblr}{
    colspec={X[l,1]*{9}{X[-0.6]}},
    column{1}={cmd=\bfseries},
    rowspec={*{6}{m{3em}}},
    row{1}={cmd=\bfseries},
    hlines,
    vlines={1,2,3,4,5,6}{solid},
}
    & \SetCell[c=3]{c} SRC && \SetCell[c=3]{c} MSRC && \SetCell[c=3]{c} NFRC & \\
    & RF1 & RF2 & ROI & RF1 & RF2 & ROI & RF1 & RF2 & ROI \\
    SVM & 0.54 & 0.59 & 0.6 & 0.629 & 0.354 & 0.513 & 0.42 & 0.634 & 0.374 \\
    DT & 0.418 & 0.433 & 0 .533 & 0.486 & 0.524 & 0.379 & 0.521 & 0.685 & 0.561 \\
    kNN & 0.387 & 0.536 & 0.498 & 0.536 & 0.579 & 0.453 & 0.652 & 0.626 & 0.652  \\
    GNB & 0.472 & 0.437 & 0.434 & 0.609 & 0.557 & 0.248 & 0.484 & 0.416 & 0.444 \\
\end{tblr}
\captionsetup{justification=centering}
\captionof{table}{my table test}
\label{table:myTable}
```

I get the following:
[image]

I simply want the other row titles (MSRC & NFRC) to appear where they belong. However, for some reason, the SRC takes over the row completely.

Comment: you need three ambersands after the setcell: `\SetCell[c=3]{c} SRC &&&` as you are spanning three cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

[image]

In MWE is considered @Ulrice comment. IN this `tabularray` differ from other table packages, where at multi column cells should be omitted ampersands, here must be present. Beside this is changed (simplified and correct set) `tblr` preamble:

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{caption}
 \usepackage{tabularray}
 
 \begin{document}
 \noindent%
 \begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
              colspec = {Q[l, font=\bfseries] *{9}{X[c]} },
              rows    = {m, ht=3em},
              row{1}  = {font=\bfseries},
              }
 \SetCell[r=2]{c}
    &   \SetCell[c=3]{c} SRC 
        &   &   &   \SetCell[c=3]{c} MSRC 
                    &   &   &   \SetCell[c=3]{c} NFRC 
                                &   &                                       \\
    & RF1   & RF2   & ROI   & RF1   & RF2   & ROI   & RF1   & RF2   & ROI   \\
SVM & 0.54  & 0.59  & 0.6   & 0.629 & 0.354 & 0.513 & 0.42  & 0.634 & 0.374 \\
DT  & 0.418 & 0.433 & 0.533 & 0.486 & 0.524 & 0.379 & 0.521 & 0.685 & 0.561 \\
kNN & 0.387 & 0.536 & 0.498 & 0.536 & 0.579 & 0.453 & 0.652 & 0.626 & 0.652 \\
GNB & 0.472 & 0.437 & 0.434 & 0.609 & 0.557 & 0.248 & 0.484 & 0.416 & 0.444 \\
\end{tblr}
\captionsetup{justification=centering}
\captionof{table}{my table test}
\label{table:myTable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Can you tell me, how can I only have 2 vertical lines separating the SRC, MSRC and NFRC ?

Comment: @syriancoffee, replace `vlines` with `vline{5,8}={solid}`, however, resulted table will become strange ,,,